# How do I make sure every glyph has the same width?

Tags: font-awesome

I've noticed that even at the same font size, there is not a standard width. How can I use these in front of a list of items so the words don't appear jagged?

Screenshot of issue:

[image]

This is the code:

```
<ul id="myTab">
    <li class="active"><a href="#home"><i class="icon-tasks"></i> Proposal</a></li>
    <li><a href="#video"><i class="icon-film"></i> Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="#asset"><i class="icon-paper-clip"></i> Assets</a></li>
    <li><a href="#payment"><i class="icon-credit-card"></i> Payment</a></li>
    <li><a href="#history"><i class="icon-calendar empty"></i> History</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 213, accepted):

Since 3.1.1, you could use the `icon-fixed-width` class instead of having to edit the CSS.

http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/examples/#navigation

Since 4.0, you should use `fa-fw`:
4.x  https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/examples/#fixed-width
5.x https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons

Thanks @kalessin for pointing out.

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure that you haven't got another style defined that is doing this?

This is how your HTML looks placed into a file on a site I have using Font Awesome:

[image]

Notice how the icons and the text line up. This is your original image with lines added:

[image]

It looks like you have a style defined somewhere that is removing the Font Awesome styling.

You could also try adding in the original Font Awesome style (coming from `font-awesome.css`) to see if that solves it temporarily:

```
li [class^="icon-"], .nav li [class^="icon-"], 
li [class*=" icon-"], .nav li [class*=" icon-"] {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 1.25em;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This was not in my font-awesome.css, nor in the file I downloaded (http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/assets/font-awesome.zip) or even in the CDN version that they reference (http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/index.html?v=05162013150137#tab_fontawesome). But it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

For Fontawesome version above **4.X**, use `fa-fw` class in the `<i>` tag.
Ref:- https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/styling/fixed-width-icons

Answer (score 2):

**Its simple and easy to scale glyph or any icon using this css**

```
> .fa { transform: scale(1.5,1); }
```