# Fontawesome Icons in Bootstrap aren't squared

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, icons, font-awesome, shapes

I use fontawesome icons for my bootstrap site but the icons don't have a squared size. How to handle the icons like if they were squared (with same width and height).
In my sidebar this [image] is the result of the icons, which shape isn't a square.You know a solution for this problem?

Maybe a solution for the problem is to create a custom class, but then how will the class be?

Thank you

Comment: Please show us the code that you used to generate the sidebar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make sure every glyph has the same width?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16592849/how-do-i-make-sure-every-glyph-has-the-same-width)

Comment: @JoostS I am sorry but it didn't display the question when created this one.

Comment: I think you're looking for `fa-fw`. Just add this class to the icons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font awesome has an optional `fa-fw` class that will render the icons at an even width.

http://fontawesome.io/examples/#fixed-width

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<ul>
  <li><i class="fa fa-external-link fa-fw"></i> Hello world!</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-mobile fa-fw"></i> Hello world!</li>
  <li><i class="fa fa-drivers-license-o fa-fw"></i> Hello world!</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer. I looked at the linked site and it should work. Satisfying answer. :)